# Design Patterns used in IOT based home automation system like Alexa

Tags: java, design-patterns, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to design a basic IOT based home automation system like Alexa or Google Home. So can anyone explain what are the basic design patterns used in Alexa or Google Home to dynamically register new devices like Lights and Fans and perform operations on them.

I have implemented this using a command pattern using fixed set of devices, but need to scale this to take care of registering dynamic run time new objects without changing code like Alexa

```
public SmartHomeDevice getSmartHomeDevice(String deviceName) {
        SmartHomeDevice smartHomeDevice = null;

        if (SmartHomeDeviceCategoryConstants.DRAWING_ROOM_LIGHT.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceName)) {
            smartHomeDevice = new Light(deviceName);
        } else if (SmartHomeDeviceCategoryConstants.LIVING_ROOM_FAN.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceName)) {
            smartHomeDevice = new Fan(deviceName);
        } else if (SmartHomeDeviceCategoryConstants.SMART_CHARGER.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceName)) {
            smartHomeDevice = new ElectricalDevice(deviceName);
        }
        return smartHomeDevice;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for data structures, not design patterns. A basic Hashmap can hold multiple uniquely named items

Answer (score 0):

For Home Automation , you have to use Command Design Pattern Refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-pattern/.

Comment: From the class diagram you can see there is invoker,reciever,command and client

Comment: From the command design pattern class diagram,there are invoker,reciever,client and command. Invoker is a remote interface that control commands. Reciever is the object you are going to control such as the light. Commands are switch on or switch off

Comment: Please include quotes and resources from the links of your post in the answer, since urls can point to dead and and the resource might be changed. If You have additional information, edit your answer instead of adding comments.